# recycle view not rendering and displaying data from firebase when run on physical device but works fine on emulator

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build a native android app in xamarin where users can sign in and upload post to the feed page and also view posts from other users on their feed. The feed page has a recycler view which renders posts from the firebase and also has an upload option for users to upload posts to firebase, which then will be retrieved back to the app and be displayed in the feed page. everything works fine on the emulator (user sign-in->user view feeds->user upload posts etc). But when I build the release file and install it on my android 10 phone, only the sign in functionality works which uses validation from firebase. The feeds recycler view does not work anymore and does not display posts from firebase, and also every time a user tries to upload a posts to firebase, the app crashes, shows the splash screen, and then finally exits. I have looked up everywhere for an answer but could not find any so I decided to seek help here. Below are some code snippets:

- activity_main.xml

```cs
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/include_main"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navview"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navheader"
            app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
              
        />

 
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

- include_main.xml

```cs
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ToolBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
                

                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                android:src="@drawable/account"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="Feed"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/layStatus"
        android:elevation="4dp">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="240dp"
           android:layout_height="36dp"           
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedges">

             <TextView
            android:text="What's on your mind?"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
            
         <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userIcon"
                android:src="@drawable/add"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        
        <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postRecycleView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

- MainActivity.cs

```cs
    using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TransGlobal.Adapter;
using TransGlobal.DataModels;
using TransGlobal.Activities;
using TransGlobal.Actvities;
using TransGlobal.EventListeners;
using System.Linq;
using TransGlobal.Helpers;
using Firebase.Storage;
using TransGlobal.Fragments;
using Android.Content;

namespace TransGlobal
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = false)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
        RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
        PostAdapter postAdapter;
        List<Post> ListOfPost;
        RelativeLayout layStatus;
        //ImageView cameraImage;
        AndroidX.DrawerLayout.Widget.DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationView navigationView;
        

       PostEventListener postEventListener;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            drawerLayout = (AndroidX.DrawerLayout.Widget.DrawerLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.drawerLayout);
            navigationView = (Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.navview);
            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;
            
            
            
            //this block of code is new since git upload
            AndroidX.AppCompat.App.ActionBar actionBar = SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.menuaction);
            actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




            postRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.postRecycleView);

            layStatus = (RelativeLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.layStatus);
            layStatus.Click += LayStatus_Click;
            //cameraImage = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.camera);
            //cameraImage.Click += LayStatus_Click;

            // Retreives fullname on Login
            FullnameListener fullnameListener = new FullnameListener();
            fullnameListener.FetchUser();

            // CreateData();
            FetchPost();
            
        }

        private void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, Google.Android.Material.Navigation.NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MenuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.navFunds)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FundsActivity));
               // intent.PutExtra("topic", "History");
                StartActivity(intent);
                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            }
            else if (e.MenuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.navHealth)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HealthActivity));
                // intent.PutExtra("topic", "History");
                StartActivity(intent);
                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            }
            else if (e.MenuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.navProfile)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ProfileActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("topic", "History");
                StartActivity(intent);
                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            }
            else if (e.MenuItem.ItemId == Resource.Id.navLogout)
            {
                postEventListener.RemoveListener();
                AppDataHelper.GetFirebaseAuth().SignOut();
                StartActivity(typeof(LoginActivity));
                Finish();
                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            }
            
        }

        private void LayStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(CreatePostActivity));
        }

        void FetchPost()
        {
            postEventListener = new PostEventListener();
            postEventListener.FetchPost();
            postEventListener.OnPostRetrieved += PostEventListener_OnPostRetrieved;
        }

        private void PostEventListener_OnPostRetrieved(object sender, PostEventListener.PostEventArgs e)
        {
            ListOfPost = new List<Post>();
            ListOfPost = e.Posts;

            if (ListOfPost != null)
            {
                ListOfPost = ListOfPost.OrderByDescending(x => x.PostDate).ToList();
            }

            SetupRecyclerView();
        }

        void CreateData()
        {
            ListOfPost = new List<Post>();
            ListOfPost.Add(new Post { PostBody = "The United States has been lobbying for months to prevent its western allies from using Huawei equipment in their 5G deployment, and on Wednesday, Washington made it more difficult for the Chinese telecom ", Author = "Uchenna Nnodim", LikeCount = 12 });
            ListOfPost.Add(new Post { PostBody = "TE Connectivity is a technology company that designs and manufactures connectivity and sensor products for harsh environments in a variety of industries, such as automotive, industrial equipment, ", Author = "Johan Gasierel", LikeCount = 34 });
            ListOfPost.Add(new Post { PostBody = "Singapore-based startup YouTrip  thinks consumers of Southeast Asia deserve a taste of the challenger bank revolution happening in the U.S. and Europe, and it has raised $25 million in new funding to bring its app-and-debit-card service to more parts in the region.", Author = "Kylie Jenna", LikeCount = 6 });
            ListOfPost.Add(new Post { PostBody = "TE Connectivity is a technology company that designs and manufactures connectivity and sensor products for harsh environments in a variety of industries, such as automotive, industrial equipment, ", Author = "Johan Gasierel", LikeCount = 78 });

        }

        void SetupRecyclerView()
        {
            postRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(postRecyclerView.Context));
            postAdapter = new PostAdapter(ListOfPost);
            postRecyclerView.SetAdapter(postAdapter);
            postAdapter.ItemLongClick += PostAdapter_ItemLongClick;
            postAdapter.LikeClick += PostAdapter_LikeClick;
        }

        private void PostAdapter_LikeClick(object sender, PostAdapterClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Post post = ListOfPost[e.Position];
            LikeEventListener likeEventListener = new LikeEventListener(post.ID);

            if (!post.Liked)
            {
                likeEventListener.LikePost();
            }
            else
            {
                likeEventListener.UnlikePost();
            }
        }

        private void PostAdapter_ItemLongClick(object sender, PostAdapterClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string postID = ListOfPost[e.Position].ID;
            string ownerID = ListOfPost[e.Position].OwnerId;

            if (AppDataHelper.GetFirebaseAuth().CurrentUser.Uid == ownerID)
            {
                AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AndroidX.AppCompat.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("Edit or Delete Post");
                alert.SetMessage("Are you sure");

                // Edit Post on Firestore
                alert.SetNegativeButton("Edit Post", (o, args) =>
                {
                    EditPostFragment editPostFragment = new EditPostFragment(ListOfPost[e.Position]);
                    var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                    editPostFragment.Show(trans, "edit");

                });

                // Delete Post from Firestore and Storage
                alert.SetPositiveButton("Delete", (o, args) =>
                {
                    AppDataHelper.GetFirestore().Collection("posts").Document(postID).Delete();
                    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.Instance.GetReference("postImages/" + postID);
                    storageReference.Delete();
                });

                alert.Show();
            }
        }

       

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {

            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    drawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }
            
        }


    }
}
```

If you need anymore code snippets of a particular class or xml, you can add a comment stating so. I will be more than happy to provide as much code snippets as I can or even provide you with the full source code. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `and also every time a user tries to upload a posts to firebase, the app crashes, shows the splash screen, and then finally exits.`  Is there any error or relative log about this problem?

Comment: you need to add some exception handling, logging and crash reporting.  AppCenter.ms is a good free tool you might start with

Comment: As I mentioned. Everything works fine on the emulator. It is only when I install it on a physical device that is facing the problems mentioned above. I can't log out errors when running the app on a physical device can I?

Comment: Just as Jason mentioned, in this condition, you can add some exception handling, logging and crash reporting(e.g. Appcenter). Even runing on a  physical device, you can also get relative log about  your app. For more, check [appcenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/). Especially [Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/).